Loader is not shown for root path in Next.js 14 app
Implementation
I am currently implementing a web app using Next.js 14. I want to add a loader component which is displayed while the page is being loaded. For this I used the loading.tsx file, just as described here. My folder structure now looks something like this:
src
|- app
|-- loading.tsx
|-- page.tsx
|-- profile 
|--- loading.tsx
|--- page.tsx

Note that the contents of the loading.tsx files are identical.
Edit
loading.tsx
import ScreenLoader from '@/components/util/screen-loader';

type Props = {};

export default function Loading({}: Props) {
  return <ScreenLoader />;
}

The ScreenLoader is just a component, which displays an image.
Problem description
Now, if I navigate to localhost:3000 to view my app, the loader is not shown. However, when accessing an arbitrary nested path (e.g. localhost:3000/profile), the loader works perfectly fine.
Why is that the case and how can I fix it so the loader is also shown for the root path?

How did you implement the loading.tsx file/function?

@realhuman: I updated the question and added the content of the loading.tsx.

Sorry for poor wording lol, I meant how did you use the loading file/function?

I did not use it at all, at least not explicitly. If you stick to the naming convention, Next.js 14 picks it up automatically.

Is your root page.tsx dynamic with an operation that takes a reasonable amount of time for you to see the loading UI? if your page component is static or loads really fast you won't see the loading UI.

It loads fast, but so do the nested paths for which I can see the loader for a short time.

Are you accessing the home page directly from the address bar, or navigating to the home page from a page element?

I've tried both, but it doesn't work either way.
